# Equation not working correctly in C++

Tags: c++

```
//Samuel LaManna
//Program 1 (intrest rate)
/*Variables:
Principal=P
Interest Rate=R
Times Compounded=T
Answer=A */

#include <iostream>                                                                        //Input/output

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  int P, R, T, A;                                                                          //Declaring Variables
  cout<<endl;
  cout<<"Interest Earned Calculator";                                                      //Prints program title
  cout<<endl;
  cout<<endl;
  cout<<"Please enter the Principal Value: ";
  cin >> P;
  cout<<endl;
  cout<<endl;
  cout<<"Please enter the Interest Rate (in decimal form): ";
  cin >> R;
  cout<<endl;
  cout<<endl;
  cout<<"Please enter the Number of times the interest is compounded in a year: ";
  cin >> T;
  cout<<endl;
  cout<<endl;
  A=P*((1+R)/T)^T;
  cout<<"Interest Rate", cout<<R;
  return 0;
}
```

When it gets to were it does the equation and starts outputting it gets all messed and thrown together. Its a simple interest calculator app.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'll guarantee that, if you're doing interest rate calculations (or anything else requiring floating point accuracy), you should *not* be using an `int` data type.

In addition `^` is not the power operator, it's the exclusive-or operator. You need to look into the `pow` standard library function.

That should hopefully be enough for you to figure out why your homework is misbehaving, without me doing all the work for you.

> Aside: The construct
>   `cout<<"Interest Rate", cout<<R;`
>   is a pretty rare one. It *may* work (I don't know off the top of my head whether the comma operator is a sequence point and I'm too lazy to go look it up at the moment), but you should probably prefer something like the more usual:
>   `cout << "Interest Rate: " << R << endl;`

And you probably want to output `A` (the answer) at some point :-)

Comment: Do i need the cmath library to use the pow function?

Comment: @Sam, you should use a floating point type (float, double, ...) and yes, `pow` is in `cmath`.

Comment: I do but the prompt has the inputs listed first for output, i gotta make it look "clean". Thanks for the help!

Comment: Im having trouble with the pow function. The equation is            A=P*((1+R)/T)^T      How would i use the pow function, i only see examples that are 4 to the 5th power, nothing like what i have to do

Comment: @Sam, some advice: if it's a new question, you should ask a new question. It's hard to format answers and questions in the comments fields and that's not really what they're for. In addition, a proper question will get a lot more eyes looking at it. But it would be something like `A = P * pow ((1+R)/T,T)` or `A = pow (P*((1+R)/T),T)` depending on whether `P` was meant to be included in the power calculation or just a multiplier following it.

Comment: Due to order of operations it would not be. I think the first one you gave is correct you are just missing a set of ()'s and i posted a new question and thanks