# C++ Float Var rounding

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Equation not working correctly in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7424615/equation-not-working-correctly-in-c)
>   [Help with POW function in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7424721/help-with-pow-function-in-c)

In This code:

```
//Samuel LaManna
//Program 1 (intrest rate)
/*Variables:
Principal=P
Interest Rate=R
Times Compounded=T
Savings=S
Interest=I */

#include <iostream>     //Input/output
#include <cmath>        //Math Functions

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  float P, R, T, S, I;                                                                      //Declaring Variables
  cout<<endl;
  cout<<"Interest Earned Calculator";                                                       //Prints program title
  cout<<endl;
  cout<<endl;
  cout<<"Please enter the Principal Value: ";
  cin >> P;
  cout<<endl;
  cout<<endl;
  cout<<"Please enter the Interest Rate (in decimal form): ";
  cin >> R;
  cout<<endl;
  cout<<endl;
  cout<<"Please enter the Number of times the interest is compounded in a year: ";
  cin >> T;
  cout<<endl;
  cout<<endl;
  S=pow(1+R/T,T)*P;    //Equation to find Savings
  I=S-P;               //Equation to find interest in $
  cout<<"Interest Rate: " << R*100 <<"%" ;
  cout<<endl;
  cout<<endl;
  cout<<"Times Compounded: " << T;
  cout<<endl;
  cout<<endl;
  cout<<"Principal: $" << P;
  cout<<endl;
  cout<<endl;
  cout<<"Interest: $" << I;
  cout<<endl;
  cout<<endl;
  cout<<"Ammount in Savings: $" << S;
  cout<<endl;
  cout<<endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Is there a way to make the final output numbers round to 2 decimal places even if they are 0?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried)

Comment: Have a look at [setprecision](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/setprecision/)

Comment: I dont even know were to start, im a student working ahead.

Comment: This is _not_ an exact duplicate, not even close. Although it's the same author and even the same underlying program, the _problem/question_ is entirely different ("use of pow" vs. "precision of cout output").

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's assume that I know nothing about what `cout` does. Because I know nothing about `cout`, I do a search engine query for "c++ cout". I click on one of the links on the first page, [such as this MSDN doucmentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bzbx67e8.aspx). According to that page, I find that `cout` is an `ostream` that outputs to the standard output. So let's look up `ostream`, [so conveniently provided in the MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c05928ed.aspx). On the `ostream` page, there's [a link called "iostream Programming"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/22z6066f.aspx). That looks promising, so let's click on that.

There's [a link called "Output Streams"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/27k0cfbh.aspx) on the "iostream Programming" page. Again, that looks promising. After all, we are outputting something to the screen, so let's take a look. On that page, there's [a link called "Using Insertion Operators and Controlling Format"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/420970az.aspx). Sounds like we're getting close.

Lo and behold, I stumble upon a page which shows "how to control format". There's a section on that page called "Precision" that describes the functions [`setprecision()` and `setiosflags()` complete with code examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/420970az.aspx#vclrfprecisionanchor5). According to the documentation, perhaps it might solve your problem.

The above process I've taken is what's often colloquially called ["RTFM"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTFM) by members of the Internet. It's a very useful technique for obtaining information on your own, and can be used to your advantage to get ahead of your peers.

Comment: What In Silico is trying to say (in a roundabout and humorous fashion) is to look up setprecision and setwidth and the iomanip header file. Just in case it was too obtuse :-)

Comment: Yeah that would be perfect if i knew that the user was always gonna input numbers with the same place value. For Principal they could input $1,000 or $1,000,000. if i set up the precision for them imputing 1,000 then it cuts numbers off if they input 1,000,000

Comment: I think i got it, if i use fixed before setprecision it will only count numbers after the decimal place